# Can I use fetch api in jquery-datatables?

Tags: ajax, datatables, fetch-api

I understand that you can use ajax to populate the datatable. But can you use fetch?
Because I have this normal table, filled dynamically using fetch api.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fillTable();
})
//fetch api (AJAX) to fill table
fillTable = () => {
fetch('http://localhost:3000/home.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    let html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        html += '<tr>'+
                    '<td class="tdUsername pv3 w-35 pr3 bb b--black-20">'+ data[i].username + '</td>'+
                    '<td class="tdPassword pv3 w-35 pr3 bb b--black-20">'+ data[i].password + '</td>'+
                    '<td class="pv3 w-30 pr3 bb b--black-20">'+
                      '<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">'+
                        '<a class="editButton f6 grow no-underline ba bw1 ph3 pv2 mb2 dib black pointer"  data-toggle="modal">EDIT</a>'+
                        '<a class="deleteButton f6 grow no-underline ba bw1 ph3 pv2 mb2 dib black pointer"  data-toggle="modal">DELETE</a>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</td>'+
                '</tr>'
    }
    $('#tblBody').html(html);
})
.catch(err => console.log("ERROR!: ", err))
}
```

So I am wondering if I can use fetch-api instead of using this to fill the datatable.

```
//syntax copied from the website
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
ajax: '/api/myData'
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use 'ajax' option as a function, see https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function

> As a function, making the Ajax call is left up to yourself allowing complete control of the Ajax request. Indeed, if desired, a method other than Ajax could be used to obtain the required data, such as Web storage or a Firebase database.
>
> When the data has been obtained from the data source, the second parameter (callback here) should be called with a single parameter passed in - the data to use to draw the table.

Example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('dataTablesData') )
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer myself as I am trying to stay away from jquery as much as possible, but was unable to find an answer anywhere.  I ultimately figured it out on my own and the implementation is not very different than using DataTable's suggested jquery ajax call.

```
        var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        ajax: async function (data, callback, settings) {
            let response = await fetch("/api/v1/some/end/point", {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("token")}});
            if (response.ok) {
                let msg = await response.json();
                sessionStorage.setItem('token', msg.token);
                console.table(msg.data);
                delete msg['token'];
                callback(msg);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        },
        ...... followed by the usual DataTable options
```

Answer (score -1):

if someone is looking for an answer.

Yes, you can use `fetch` to populate `datatable`, here is an example.

```
fetchEndPointData(dc)
    .then(aggregatedData => {
        $('#table1').dataTable().api().rows.add(aggregatedData);
    }).catch(error => {
      // When fetch ends with a bad HTTP status, e.g. 404
      console.log(error.message);
    });
```

invoked method

```
async function fetchEndPointData(dc) {
  const response = await fetch('/someEndPoint=' + dc);
  const movies = await response.json();
  return movies;
}
```

Note : the `fetchEndPointData` is returning a promise.

reference : https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/